# C# - User Login only checking the newest record for the username

Tags: c#, sql, authentication, system

I am making a login system using C#, which successfully checks if the user's credentials match up, but for some reason, whenever I write a username that is not the newest record, it gives me the "Username doesn't exist" error, but if it is written with the correct password, it still logs in.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data source=(local);Initial Catalog=GameStore;Integrated Security=True";
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Staff", conn);

            //Username
            String TextBoxUsername = textBox1.Text;
            //Lower Casing
            TextBoxUsername = TextBoxUsername.ToLower();
            //Password
            String TextBoxPassword = textBox2.Text;      

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //Username
                    string DatabaseUsername = (string)reader["StaffUserName"];
                    //Lower Casing
                    DatabaseUsername = DatabaseUsername.ToLower();
                    //Password
                    string DatabasePassword = (string)reader["StaffPassword"];


                    //If Username Matches One In DB
                    if (DatabaseUsername == TextBoxUsername)
                    {
                        WarningLabel.Visible = false;
                        WarningLabel.Text = "";

                        //If Password Matches One In DB
                        if(DatabasePassword == TextBoxPassword)
                        {
                            WarningLabel.Visible = false;
                            WarningLabel.Text = "";
                            MessageBox.Show("Logging In");
                        }
                        //Wrong Password
                        else
                        {
                            WarningLabel.Visible = true;
                            WarningLabel.Text = "Incorrect Password";
                        }

                    }

                    //Username doesn't exist in DB
                    else

                    {
                        WarningLabel.Visible = true;
                        WarningLabel.Text = "Username doesn't exist";

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image][image][image]

Comment: Add parameters to the command, that way you don't have to do the whole _using_ thing (if you have many users, you'll iterate over all of them). If your reader has results, then you have a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that's cause you are doing a `select * ...` and storing the data in same `string` variable which overwrites all the data and obviously remains with the last record and thus the behavior

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //Username
                string DatabaseUsername = (string)reader["StaffUserName"];
```

Better would be filter the record based on your input like below and then your posted code should work fine

```
select * from stuff
where StaffUserName = @uname
and StaffPassword = @pwd;
```

Comment: ah I completely overlooked that, what can I possibly do about it? store it in an array?

Comment: @MarsBars9459, see edit in answer if that helps. moreover do some reading on authentication system